# how to fast deploy lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, sam

how to deploy lambda fast in project?
Update an existing lambda, we can use `sls deploy -f functionName`,
but add or delete a lambda is so slow,Is there any way to quickly add or delete a lambda function?

I hope to add or delete a lambda function into a project that has managed multiple lambdas (such as sam, serverless, amplify), but it is slow when I deploy. I know that updating a lambda can take 20s~30s quickly (for example, serverless, or sam has a better command for updating a single existing cloudformation), but if I add 1 lambda to a project that already has 100 lambdas When I deploy using sls or sam, it seems to redeploy 101 lambdas, even if I only want to add one. Is there a better way to go to the cloudformation stack containing 100 lambdas or delete 1 lambda?

Comment: HI Ddd, can you please go into more detail? What are you actually doing? What part of it is slow? Based on your description it could be a number of things: your computer, your build process, your internet connection. Can you add some numbers and which steps exactly you are doing?

Comment: I hope to add or delete a lambda function into a project that has managed multiple lambdas (such as sam, serverless, amplify), but it is slow when I deploy. I know that updating a lambda can take 20s~30s quickly (for example, serverless, or sam has a better command for updating a single existing cloudformation), but if I add 1 lambda to a project that already has 100 lambdas When I deploy using sls or sam, it seems to redeploy 101 lambdas, even if I only want to add one. Is there a better way to go to the cloudformation stack containing 100 lambdas or delete 1 lambda?

Answer (score 0):

You can now use SAM Accelerate to quickly iterate over your application. This will help fast deploy the lambda you modified within seconds. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/speeding-up-incremental-changes-with-aws-sam-accelerate-and-nested-stacks/